# Taking bath at night / 3 AM

Tags: bath

I realize Brahm Muhurat begins at 4 AM (or is it 4:30 AM?) but can one take bath and perform morning ablutions starting at 3 AM?

Comment: No, one should not take bath at 3 AM. I'm sure about it, but have to search for a reference.

Comment: If it's the modern age bath i e. Shower then can take anytime. But bathing as per scriptures takes place in river with some associates nitya karma. There are specific time period during which one can take those baths including the fact that you have to be clothed

Comment: Thanks a million for both responses but they are not consistent so I am more confused. I live in the US so it’s really the daily shower in a contemporary bathroom. What is the earliest I can take a shower? It’s just that I have a long work commute and sometimes I have to be there fairly early and want to do some puja before setting out for which I need to be showered.